# Netty 4.x HTTP 1.1 pipelining support

Tags: netty

Does Netty support HTTP pipelining and if so, what classes should be used?

Doesn't seem to be anything about in the docs or examples and I know Typesafe guys are making a library with said support for Netty, but it's for an older Netty version at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be done following the logic made by Typesafe, adapting the code to Netty 4.X. However might be a good idea to look at HTTP2 support that could bring the very same ?